# PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test not found in CakePHP

Tags: php, phpunit, cakephp-2.2

I'm able to run my individual tests for each model in a plugin called Agg, but when I try to run a [CakeTestSuite](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#creating-test-suites), then I get an error.

```
class ModelsTest extends CakeTestSuite
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new CakeTestSuite('All model tests');
        $suite->addTestDirectory(TESTS . 'Case' . DS . 'Model');
        return $suite;
    }
}
```

Running that suite generates this error.

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test' not found in C:\work\zend\cake\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php on line 77

I'm using PHP 5.3.15 and have PHPUnit 3.7.12 installed with CakePHP 2.2.5

I get this error when running tests both via the web and the CLI.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

If I search for 'PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test' in PEAR folder for PHPUnit it's not found. This seems strange to me. Am I using the wrong version of PHPUnit? When was this class introduced?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that this class is no longer used in PHPUnit 3.7.x, and I'm wondering if CakePHP 2.2 will only work with PHPUnit 3.6. I tried to uninstall the pear package, and then install the 3.6.x version but always installs the newest version. Any ideas on how to downgrade PHPUnit?

**UPDATE:**

Downgrading using the --force to install older versions of PHPUnit didn't resolve the problem. I tried 3.6.12, 3.6.5 and 3.5. With the 3.6.12 I got an error with is_file() somewhere in the PHPUnit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test` is available in PHPUnit 3.6, see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php

I suggest uninstalling *all* phpunit packages and reinstalling phpunit 3.6 with

```
$ pear install phpunit/phpunit-3.6.12
```

It might be that dependencies were broken when downgrading the single phpunit package with `--force`, and this should fix it.

Comment: thanks. I'll try 3.6.12 again and see if I can get it to work.