# PHPUnit intallation for CakePHP 2.4

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, composer-php

Error that I'm getting when trying to run tests:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_Diff' not found in Cake/TestSuite/Reporter/CakeHtmlReporter.php on line 267
```

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348318/phpunit-util-skeleton-test-not-found-in-cakephp), and the answers there, I need to install PHPUnit 3.6.x to avoid the missing Class error. How can I install this, now deprecated, version?

I've tried using composer like this:

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=3.6.*"
```

But I get the following error

```
 Problem 1
    - The requested package phpunit/phpunit could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

I've tried PEAR with this command:

```
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.6.12
```

but I get this error:

```
Attempting to discover channel "phpunit"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "phpunit"...
unknown channel "phpunit" in "phpunit/phpunit-3.6.12"
invalid package name/package file "phpunit/phpunit-3.6.12"
install failed
```

I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345021/using-phpunit-in-cakephp-windows-7) which points me to [dereuromark's plugin](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-phpunit), which is deprecated and suggests that I use composer since the pear channel for PHPUnit has been shutdown. Not to mention that it's version 3.7.x, which is missing the Class I need. So, I've come full circle.

tl;dr **How do install PHPUnit 3.6.x for the CakePHP 2.4.x?**

**UPDATE**: I checked that the same class is used in the latest CakePHP 2.x version. Also, I should mention that test ran correctly on a similar, but older VM that had the older PHPUnit installed.

Comment: The class is there just fine in the [**3.7**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.7.38/PHPUnit/Util/Diff.php) as well as the [**3.6**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6.12/PHPUnit/Util/Diff.php) branch.

Comment: @ndm oh man, I totally missed it... I managed to mix up the class the other SO question was missing (which is missing in 3.7) with the ones I needed. Ok, an update will fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: PHPUnit 3.6 is no longer available for installation.

PHPUnit 3.6 was only ever available as a PEAR package. [The PEAR Channel that hosted PHPUnit, pear.phpunit.de, was shut down on December 31, 2014.](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see that even 3.7 has what I need, I shouldn't have blindly followed the other SO question/answer...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to workaround the issue. Since I wasn't able to install the deprecated PHPUnit version, I took the missing functions from the [Diff](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Util/Diff.php) class(diff, diffToArray and longestCommonSubsequence) and put them into the CakeHtmlReporter Class, since that was the only one referencing them.

After that I changed `PHPUnit_Util_Diff::diff` to `self::diff` and it's working now, even though it's missing the old CSS styles, but I can live with that.

It's not the answer to the question I asked, but maybe it can help someone else, until a better answer comes along.